# How to get file path of any text file and read it from SD card in Android?

Tags: java, android, sd-card

I have got so many links related to image file but didn't get any text related. There is solution for specific text file to open but I need general solution and not hard coded file location on SD card. I'm building an Android app that gets (copyies) the link of the file in `TextView` and reads the content of that file in another `TextView` from SD card. One button which is used to open the SD card:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("text/plain"); //open only for text file 
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            //broadcast the supported media to choose for file to open 
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file"), MY_INTENT_CLICK);
        }
```

This is the code for onActivityResult()

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == MY_INTENT_CLICK) {
            if (data == null) return;

            //String sel_file_path;
            String sel_file_path;
            Uri sel_file_uri = data.getData();

            sel_file_path = FileText.getPath (getApplicationContext(), sel_file_uri);
            setTextViews (sel_file_path);       
        }
    }
}
```

After getting the file path from `FileText` it views the link and content of text file using this method.

```
//show the link and display the content of the file 
private void setTextViews(String sel_file_path) {

    //copy the file link to textview
    this.txtpath.setText("File path: " +sel_file_path);

    //display the text file
    try {

        File file1 = new File(sel_file_path);
        //System.out.println("Path : " + file1);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String datatoread = "";
        String inBuffer = "";

        //Read the line of the file, store it in temporary variable and append it to inBuffer
        while ((datatoread = br.readLine()) != null) {
            inBuffer += datatoread + "\n";                   
        }

        txtdsp.setText(inBuffer);
        br.close();
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Load file reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Log.d("MainActivity", "File Path: "+sel_file_path); 
}
```

I got the an error while running on a device:

> no such file or directory

Comment: You are logging `sel_file_path`. What does it look like? Also, what is `FileText.getPath()`? And how are you handling `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` results that do *not* return files, but instead return `Uri` values pointing to `ContentProviders`?

Comment: @CommonsWare [FileText] is another class from there we get the path of the any file that are selected and return that file path location to [sel_file_path] string if you want code then I will mail you. From [ACTION_GET_CONTENT] it pop up a window and you select the file reader which already install in you mobile like quick-office.

Comment: "if you want code then I will mail you" -- I am not interested in the code. However, it may have bugs, or your use of it may have bugs. Suffice to say that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` returns a `Uri`, and [a `Uri` is not necessarily a file](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

Comment: yes its true that it return the Uri. I get the file path from this and paste the Uri in textview and from that text link read the content of the file. If you have any other idea on that area can you provide me some link to get rid of this issue, if possible them mail me some code snippet thank you..